# Apache2 error on restart command

Tags: networking, server, apache2

I have a problem with apache2 when I try to restart it, apache works correctly but I just can't restart him I have a Webmin server, pi-hole, ntopng and a page with 2 words on it. Here are my logs :

```
  root@SERVER:~# systemctl status apache2.service
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-12-15 15:55:57 UTC; 18s ago
  Process: 14827 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Dec 15 15:55:57 SERVER apachectl[14827]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
Dec 15 15:55:57 SERVER apachectl[14827]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
Dec 15 15:55:57 SERVER apachectl[14827]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Dec 15 15:55:57 SERVER apachectl[14827]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Dec 15 15:55:57 SERVER apachectl[14827]: Action 'start' failed.
Dec 15 15:55:57 SERVER apachectl[14827]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Dec 15 15:55:57 SERVER systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 15 15:55:57 SERVER systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Dec 15 15:55:57 SERVER systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 15 15:55:57 SERVER systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The code from journalctl -xe was a little laggy he is [here](https://pastebin.com/H4PNB7Gb)

and here is the bug that it make when i try to restart :

```
service apache2 restart
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -me" for details.
```

Could you help me?
Thx,
Poli

Comment: see `https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/CouldNotBindToAddress` it might still be running check lsof -i:80 to see opened processes on port; try use `systemctl stop/start apache2.service` instead of restart

Comment: Something is already running on port 80.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If binding to addresss is the problem(according to the logs), that means another program is probably using that port/address(80). You can find that program and stop it so that the port will be free for `apache2`.

Try the following these steps:

1. Enter `sudo netstat -plant`
   This will give you the all the programs holding certain ports. Search for the programs which is holding the port "`:::80`" (or "`0.0.0.0:80`"). Save its PPID(PPID is the number just before the program name).
2. Enter `sudo kill <PPID>`, where '' is the saved PPID from the previous step.
   This will stop the program which is using that port.
3. Now the port would be free to use. (re)start your apache2 server.

Source: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/CouldNotBindToAddress